# Java Waiting on multiple Threads, that might create new Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `Thread A`, which creates a `new Thread B`.
This `Thread B` may create `new Threads`, which also may create `new Threads`.
My `thread A` needs to wait for all other Threads to finish.

My first attempt was to add all threads to a list.

```
private List<TestcaseExecutionThread> threads = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
// inside my run function
Iterator<TestcaseExecutionThread> it = threads.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    TestcaseExecutionThread t = it.next();
    while (t.isRunning()) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`Thread A` goes through all elements of the list and just calls a function in a loop, which returns wether the current thread in the list is still running.
With a normal `ArrayList` after the first thread has finished, this goes into a `Deadlock`.
I then used a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but `Thread A` always leaves the outer Loop after the first thread.

There must be a simple solution to that problem

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Indeed, the simplest solution is probably going to look very different from how you're imagining it currently. You might find out that you're not even explicitly creating any threads.

Comment: My `Thread A` shall wait for all other Threads to finish and then notify the `GUI Thread` that the job has been done.
Currently Thread A is an instance of `TestExecution` which implements the `Runnable` interface. It provides a method which creates a new thread and adds it to the list. The other created threads call this method. `Thread A` creates at the beginnning of the execution the first `Thread B`.
I know that the threads are all created and executed. But my Thread A just exits the loop too soon

Comment: Have you considered using `CompletableFuture` for this? You can create versatile task sequences with very little manual handling for different situations. You wouldn't even have to *wait* for anything, since you could compose the sequence so that the GUI is notified when the sequence is completed.

Comment: Currently your loop uses an iterator, but the list could be modified while your iterating.

Comment: Or consider using a [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) then instead of starting/adding threads to a list you can awaitQuiescence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#arrive()) to accomplish this. I've wrapped the logic in a new class `MyThread`, which you should use in place of `Thread` anywhere you require the behaviour you're looking for:

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    MyThread(final Runnable runnable, final Phaser phaser)
    {
        super(() -> {
            runnable.run();
            phaser.arrive();
        });
        phaser.register();
    }
}
```

Here is example usage. The main thread creates a thread ("A"), which itself creates a thread ("B"). The main thread waits until all threads are done:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

    new MyThread(
        () -> {
            new MyThread(() -> System.out.println("B"), phaser).start();
            System.out.println("A");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for 1s to prove main thread is really waiting
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        },
        phaser
    ).start();

    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();

    System.out.println("Everything is done");
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nifty as a straight answer, and as a "natural" use case for `Phaser`.

Comment: I will look into Phaser, seems like this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Ill throw out the least intrusive way to solve this issue. Replace this.

```
private List<TestcaseExecutionThread> threads = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

With a Queue

```
private Queue<TestcaseExecutionThread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
```

Now your loop should be:

```
while (threads.size()>0) {
    TestcaseExecutionThread t = threads.poll();
    while (t.isRunning()) {
         try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

Really though, your "threads" should be a `Queue<Future<?>>`, then you don't need the inner while loop. But that would involve changing the structure, and instead of calling "Thread#start" you would submit it to an executor service, and add the returned future to the Queue.

Comment: TIL that LinkedList implements Queue... Is it appropriate though? Threads that spawn threads will need to be able to add their child threads to the data structure, and so you need a thread-safe collection.

Comment: @Michael I don't think it is a very good solution because of the way the data structure would be exposed. Also, I don't *think* add/poll will cause a CME, but I don't know. It appeared that the problem op was having was draining the `List<> threads`. So I thought this solution would represent the original design.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ExecutorService` and `Future`s.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); // or similar

public void run() {
    List<Future<?> futures = runnables.stream().map(service::submit).collect(toList());
    futures.forEach(Future::get);
}
```

This will call `ExecutorService.submit` for each of your `Runnable`s and then call `get` on each returned `Future` so all executions will have finished at the end.

As matt commented though, it does sound like a `ForkJoinPool` is the better way to do this, but that depends on your actual runnables.

Comment: My problem is: At the beggining of the execution I dont know how many threads there may be. They are created during execution

Comment: @oliverleo How so? At the time you arrive at `while(it.hasNext())`, you won't be adding more `Runnable`s.

Comment: @daniu I think the point is that every `Runnable` may itself create more threads.

Comment: @slim I get that, but they can use the same mechanism for waiting for those.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a synchronized list:

```
private List<Thread> threads = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

and an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
    threads.get(i).join();
}
```